# Using static markup extension in FontSize leads to invalid cast when using XAMLC

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Now I tried to activate the XAMLC compiler, but I get

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

It stops on `InitializeComponent ()`.

It works fine with

```
<Button Text="7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"
            FontSize="36" BorderRadius="0"
            Clicked="OnSelectNumber" />
```

but crashes with

```
<Button Text="7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black"
            FontSize="{x:Static local:SharedResources.ButtonFontSize}" BorderRadius="0"
            Clicked="OnSelectNumber" />
```

Here are my settings:

Prefix:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Calculator.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Calculator">
```

SharedResources.cs:

```
namespace Calculator
{
    public static class SharedResources
    {
        public static string ButtonFontSize
        {
            get { return "36"; }
        }
    }
}
```

So it seems that there are problems with `string` and `FontSize`. What can I do to make this work? I'm testing on iOS simulator (iOS 9.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FontSize` should return as a `double` (not as a `string`):

```
public static class SharedResources
{
    public static double ButtonFontSize
    {
        get { return 36; }
    }
}
```

> FontSize - the font size as a double.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/

Comment: I was irritated, because in XAML it is a string, which is then converted to a double. With `double` it works.